# using GREP and AWK to extract a value of a substring from a file

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, awk, grep

I have a file called **grepExamples** like :

```
ALUMNI=([123]="Jonas" [124]="Anna") 
TEACHERS=([123]="John" [124]="Carol")
```

to be read as

```
ALUMNI=(
    [123]="Jonas"
    [124]="Anna"
    )
TEACHERS=(
    [123]="John"
    [124]="Carol"
    )
```

and I want to make a function to extract the name, givend the role and the id

I trying with greps like

```
grep -HiRE "(ALUMNI)[^)]*((123)\W+)([A-Z][a-z]+)(\")" --include \grepExamples
grep -HiRE "(ALUMNI)[^)]*((124)\W+)([A-Z][a-z]+)(\")" --include \grepExamples
```

that allow me to identify the part of the string interested to me

and so with

```
grep -HiRE "(ALUMNI)[^)]*((123)\W+)" --include \grepExamples
grep -HiRE "(ALUMNI)[^)]*((124)\W+)" --include \grepExamples
```

that allows me to point to the text just before the Value I need

but if I try to pipe to awk, I can not get the name per se

with the first examples

```
$ grep -HiRE "(ALUMNI)[^)]*((123)\W+)" --include \grepExamples
grepExamples:ALUMNI=([123]="Jonas" [124]="Anna")

$ grep -HiRE "(ALUMNI)[^)]*((123)\W+)" --include \grepExamples | awk '{ print $1; }'
grepExamples:ALUMNI=([123]="Jonas"

$ grep -HiRE "(ALUMNI)[^)]*((123)\W+)" --include \grepExamples | awk '{ print $2; }'
[124]="Anna")
```

not sure how to continue ...

---

all I want is to searhch for alumni 123, and get Jonas
o for teacher 124 and get Carol
(and so on)

Comment: So, what's the expected output?

Comment: for alumni 123, Jonas

Comment: Please, edit complete expected output to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: I just did it on the post

Comment: I'm not fully sure about your question, but does `grep -ioP 'alumni.*\[123]="\K[^"]+(?=")'` and `grep -ioP 'teacher.*\[124]="\K[^"]+(?=")'` give you the expected output? (this doesn't need awk, and I'm assuming you have GNU grep with PCRE option available)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This seems like a grep question, with a little bit of [xy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a%20communication%20problem%20encountered,believe%20will%20allow%20them%20to%20resolve%20issue%20X.) to it. I would suggest to remove the [tag:awk] tag as it is unclear if you are looking for alternatives in pure awk (in that case, please remove the [tag:grep] tag).

Answer (score 0):

This little awk command might help:

```
awk -v role=TEACHERS -v id=124 -F'[=()" ]*' \
    '$1==role{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){if($i=="["id"]"){print $(i+1)}}}' file
Carol
```

Explanation as multiline script:

*search.awk*

```
BEGIN {
    # Gives us records like this
    # ALUMNI [123] Jonas [124] Anna  
    # TEACHERS [123] John [124] Carol
    FS="[=()\" ]*"
}

# When the first field matches the role ...
$1==role {
    # loop through id fields
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){
        # if the id matches, print the name
        if($i=="["id"]"){
            print $(i+1)
        }
    }   
}
```

To run the script:

```
awk -v role=TEACHERS -v id=124 -f search.awk file
```